# How to create dynamic states and update it in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have list of data getting fetched from the API and each index in data is creating a `<div>` which consist of some information and button along with it.

Now when I click on button, a `textarea` and submit button should open for that `<div>` and closes when clicked again.

I tried to create this [here](https://codepen.io/vinayskywalker/pen/MWVNMwN?editors=1010).

To achieve this, I am creating n number of states and update the state when user click the button.

How can I achieve this and where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example of what you're looking for:

```
const { useState } = React;

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  const data = [
    {"id":100},
    {"id":200},
    {"id":300},
    {"id":400},
  ];
  
  const [show,setShow] = useState([]);
  
  const handleClick = id => e => {
    const showCopy = [...show];
    
    if(show[id]){
      showCopy[id] = false;
    } else {
      showCopy[id] = true;
    }
    
    setShow(showCopy);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {
        data.map((k,v) => (
          <div key={v}>
            <div>
              <p>Data{v+1}</p>
              <p>Some More Information</p>
            </div>
            <button onClick={handleClick(v)}>Update</button>
            <br/>
            {
              show[v] ? <div>
                  <textarea></textarea>
                  <button id={v}>Delete</button>
              </div> : <></>
            }
            <hr/>
            
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

A couple things were wrong in your sample code:

1. Improper use of dot operators instead of brace operators

The JS dot (`.`) operator is used to access named attributes associated with the given JS object. In these particular cases, the values `v` and `id` are dynamic, and not the true names of the attributes desired. Using the brace `[]` operators allows you to access the dynamic value stored in the variable.

2. Improper array state update

In your example, the code you had written was creating a new array based on the contents of the previous array and adding a new object every time with a literal attribute named `id`. In the updated code, a copy of the original state array is created and the desired boolean value with index `id` is modified.

Comment: Just FYI, this code is mutating the `show` state (*`showCopy` is just a reference to the `show` state*). You should create a copy prior to updating state and nested state.

Comment: I'd suggest using a functional state update with a more Boolean Zen approach: `setShow(show => show.map((el, index) => index === id ? !el : el))`.